# Projection Algorithm Issues

Tags: 3d, desmos

So, I've beem working on a basic 3D Renderer on desmos using this formula for projection:
V(x,y,z)=v(x-X_cam,y-Y_cam,-z-zZ_cam)

However, when I step backwards, everything in the scene moves apart instead of just getting smaller. How would I remedy this? The full thing is here:
[3D Renderer](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xzupwubvey)